# Logic of Set Theory & Partially Order (Informative Discussion)

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, field-theory

My final exam passed but, honestly I want to understand what this (Question 4) problem means because I don't know what it is asking for. I am a undergraduate, so it would be most helpful if the explanation is easy and simple somehow?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LbOE.jpg

Somehow the chain C, suppose to lead to upper bound relating to Zorn's Lemma?

Comment: It would benefit you to type up all your posts. Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

No. Who said anything about Zorn's Lemma? Zorn's Lemma has nothing to do with this.

You're supposed to show that

> *If $C$ is a chain of sets with respect to inclusion, then for every finite subset $F$ of $\bigcup C$, there is $X\in C$ such that $F\subseteq X$*.

The suggested proof is by induction on $\lvert F\rvert$.